# How to fix "hairline" crack in vinyl dashboard

Tags: mazda, dashboard, cracking

I have a 2009 Mazda 6, and within the past few months it has developed a "hairline" crack in the soft, vinyl side of the dashboard; I'm not 100% sure it's vinyl, but it's some soft plastic material that is thick, not the hard plastic molding on other parts of the dashboard. The crack is very thin, but large. I purchased a tube of the Gorilla Glue brand silicone caulking, but the tip of the tube was much too large to get the caulk into the crack. In the end I was left with a crack covered on the surface by the caulk. However, the caulking is easily just rubbed off with your fingertip, so now the coating of the caulking is not even there.

Any other suggestions for how to fill such a thin crack to prevent it from worsening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options here.

1. Clean and condition the dashboard/dashpad, and reduce the exposure to sun it receives, to reduce additional cracks. This is the easiest solution, obviously it leaves the crack visible. Clean with a mild hand-soap and warm water, protect with a UV Protectant like 303 Aerospace protectant. Make use of a "Sun-Shield" or "Windshield Visor" when parked in an area of sun exposure.

*Avoid any "protectants" which have Petroleum/Petroleum-Byproducts/Distillates/etc, as they will harm the dash pad.* Petroleum-based products will leach the "plasticisers" from the materials, causing them to become brittle and ultimately crack.

Any "proper" method of taking care of the crack is going to require a lot more effort.

2. [This Link Here](https://www.polyvance.com/Repair-Cracked-Dashboard/) is an example of a professional repair procedure. As you can see it's involved, and requires professional equipment, and materials, which may not be easily obtainable.
3. Another option would be to use a Flexible Body Filler and a Rubber-Coating like PlastiDip. Like discussed in this [This Forum Link](https://ls1tech.com/forums/paint-body-work/1636149-plastidip-dash-pad.html) or [Link Here](http://forums.pelicanparts.com/porsche-911-technical-forum/768405-recovered-my-dashboard-plasti-dip.html)
4. The best way if you want to maintain the "factory" aspect of it would be to go to a professional Body-shop/Automotive Upholstery, and have them perform a repair or replacement of the dash pad.
5. You could, if so motivated, seek a new, or used dash-pad from a salvage yard, and replace it yourself. This is likely the cheapest method, depending on the availability of that model in your region, the cost of your time, and the fact that it will be original equipment (maintain resale value)

I hope this helps.